# MtGox websockets api returning "400 Bad Request"

Tags: mtgox, api, c#

I want to get started with the Mt. Gox websockets API, but I can't seem to get a good response from the server.

I'm sending the following (captured with Wireshark):

```
GET /mtgox HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: websocket-sharp/1.0
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: websocket.mtgox.com
Sec-WebSocket-Key: LtH+YFgnW1N8KDLDbocsUQ==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
```

and the server responds:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

I've tried sending the handshake via telnet and with this C# code and I still get a 400 Bad Request error:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ClientWebSocket ws = new ClientWebSocket();
        Task connectionTask = ws.ConnectAsync(new Uri("ws://websocket.mtgox.com/mtgox"), CancellationToken.None);
        Console.Write("Connecting");
        while (!connectionTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            Console.Write(".");
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(ws.State);
    }
}
```

(The last line printed is "Closed" and when I inspect the handshake with Wireshark I see the same 400 Bad Request)

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I can't see much documentation or samples using the websockets API so I don't really have anything to compare to :(

In response to sta's suggestion, I tried this (using WebsocketSharp):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WebSocket ws = new WebSocket("ws://websocket.mtgox.com/mtgox");
    ws.Origin = "http://websocket.mtgox.com";
    ws.Connect();
    ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", e.Data);
        }
    };
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", ws.IsAlive);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This displays `FALSE` so there's still something I'm doing wrong :/ I haven't had a chance to dig into WebSocketSharp yet though

Update:
With WebsocketSharp setting the Origin header correctly, Wireshark shows the mtgox server accepting the websocket upgrade:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n
Upgrade: websocket\r\n
Connection: Upgrade\r\n
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: 2+1ghzJ/Itt6w1aBdUteghcsJHk=\r\n
\r\n
```

But WebSocketSharp still reports the connection as closed :(

Comment: Funny, I just noticed the same thing, but I'm writing a websocket client for node.js.

Comment: There seems to be a big difference between websocket.mtgox.com/mtgox server and the socketio.mtgox.com/mtgox... The sample Loourr posted below works for socketio (slightly different handshake) but I'm still not sure why I can't connect to the websocket one (with C# WebSockets or this websockets implementation for node: https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node )

Comment: Can i try to do it with other channel?
ticker.BTCEUR,ticker.BTCAUD...etc
Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the client should send the Origin header in opening handshake to the MtGox server.

If you use current websocket-sharp, you should do like the following before connecting.

`ws.Origin = "http://websocket.mtgox.com";`

Could you try?

Update:

Could you try again the following code?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://websocket.mtgox.com/mtgox?Currency=USD");
    ws.Origin = "http://websocket.mtgox.com";
    ws.OnOpen += (sender, e) =>
    {
      ws.Send(
@"{
    ""op"": ""unsubscribe"",
    ""channel"": ""d5f06780-30a8-4a48-a2f8-7ed181b4a13f""
}"
      );
    };
    ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", e.Data);
        }
    };
    ws.Connect();
    Console.ReadLine();
    ws.Close();
}
```

It seems that an exception has occurred when the client is receiving ticker type data in a while.

I'll investigate a little further.

Update:

I've found out the cause of the exception, and fixed websocket-sharp.

Could you try your code with current websocket-sharp?

Comment: I just tried this and WebsocketSharp reports the connection to be closed: (added the code to the question)

Comment: This using wss:// works!

Answer (score 0):

For one the url should be `websocket.mtgox.com/mtgox`. Here is a [sample project](https://github.com/arthurpham/node-mtgox-socketio-client) which uses the node.js socket.io library.

I dont have much experience in C#, but here is an implementation in node.js

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io.connect( 'https://socketio.mtgox.com/mtgox' );

var message = {
  "op": "subscribe",
  "channel": "24e67e0d-1cad-4cc0-9e7a-f8523ef460fe" // this is the market depth channel
};

socket.send(JSON.stringify(message));

socket.on('message', function(message) { console.log(message); });
```

This will log market depth changes to the console.

Comment: Don't have reputation to vote up :( Thanks though! I'm going to try and figure out how the Node.JS example handshakes differently...
Changing my code to connect to https://socketio.mtgox.com/mtgox instead of what I had results in the server immediately closing the connection (doesn't even send a bad request response)

Comment: Glad it helped. You can except an answer as correct however ;-)

Comment: I'd like to use the raw websocket api. Socket.io creates bad abstractions.